# Ember application into AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ember.js

I am having issues with my dependencies when uploading an ember frontend app into S3 AWS hosted on my website. Here are 2 methods I have tried:

- Uploading to S3 from git via CircleCi into S3
- Uploading directly from terminal into S3

These are the steps I used to push the app into S3:

1)ember install ember-cli-deploy-build
2)ember build
3)ember install ember-cli-deploy-s3
4)ember deploy production --verbose --active=true

Using these commands it is rebuilding the application before uploading, I was just wondering if there's a way I can upload all my local files exactly as is into S3 and avoid the rebuild process (As the app works perfectly locally before deploy)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: In frontend JS, it's common / required to rebuild for production, because there is a _lot_ of debug tooling code that is stripped for production deploys to make a site as fast as possible

Answer (score 0):

just use aws-cli? once authenticated you can do `aws cp --recursive your-folder s3://bucket

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

and to authenticate with mfa:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/

Comment: I think I gave an ok solution, I could have expended more on it but got a vote down without any message. A pity...